# How to replace spring property placeholders in a simple java program

Tags: java, properties-file

I am working with Java and spring boot apps. I have a property file which needs to be added as environmental variables for a docker image at run time. Some of the properties are filtered through the existing Environment when they are used via placeholders as below.

```
app.name=MyApp
app.description=${app.name} is a Spring Boot application
```

I am writing a sample java file to read this property file and create a map object with some filtered properties. In this process how can I replace the placeholders with the actual property values?

I have tried looking for a key and replacing using `getProperty` method. But I would like to avoid looking up hard coded property key names in order to avoid maintenance difficulties. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new `Properties` descendant, with a method that gets a property value, and replaces any references, if any.

Something like this:

```
class MyProperties extends Properties
{
    // Constructors, as needed
    private Pettern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}");
    public String getString(final String key)
    {
        final String value = getProperty(key);
        if (null == value)
            return null;
        final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
        while (m.find())
        {
            final String refKey = m.group(1);
            final String refValue = getProperty(refKey);
            m.appendReplacement(result, null == refValue ? refKey : refValue);
        }
        m.appendTail(result);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly...Thank you very much 
would like to point out a typo here  in second line

private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}");

Answer (score 4):

Replace the named token with numbered token and use the [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class of Java SE.  It allows you to do exactly what you ask for.

Assuming props contains all the properties loaded from your file.

```
MessageFormat.format((String) props.get("app.description"),((String) props.get("app.name"));
```

Here your property shall be :

`app.description={0} is a Spring Boot application`

Else you will need to write a custom

Comment: this code segment does not replace the placeholder value. It remains the same as ${1}

Comment: @Sathya see the code in action [here](https://ideone.com/yEeXHn) . I added the wrong placeholder initially. edited it

Comment: @babs noted the edit. Thanks. but as Usagi points out it's still hard coding the keys